# Private Route Doesn't redirect to login Page

Tags: reactjs, react-context

**PrivateRoute does not redirect to the login page it is still public. What is the problem?
this is the code...**

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react'; 
    import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AuthContext from '../context/auth/AuthContext';
        
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
        const { isAuthenticated, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);
        
        return (
            <Route
              {...rest}
              render={props =>
                !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
                  <Redirect to='/login' />
                ) : (
                  <Component {...props} />
                )
              }
            />   
        ); 
    };
```

Comment: Can you check if loading is true or false?

Comment: loading is true @HarshaVenkatram

Comment: In your condition, the only way that the person will be redirected to the login page is if they are not authenticated **and** the page is not loading.    I would think you want to redirect regardless of the loading state if they are not authenticated.

Comment: const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
    errors: null
  };

Comment: what sets `loading` to `false`. When does it happen? You might be running into a race condition where `loading` is still `true` when PrivateRoute is being rendered.